# jquery nestable cannot drag to an empty list

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, list, jquery-ui-sortable

The page I am developing requires that there be two lists, one of which to add items to and then order those items. I am using Jquery plugin called nestable where you can drag and drop list items. it works fine when there are items prepopulated in the list, but when i make an empty list i cannot drag items onto it. I have tried using the dd-empty class everywhere (divs in different locations the ol class, the li class) and nothing seems to work completely. The closest thing that works is setting the ol class to dd-empty. it creates an empty "slot" which i can drag one item to, however it does not allow me to drag anymore items or drag that item back to the original list.

Am i doing something wrong? maybe in my CSS? or is this just a bug that nestable has?

Let me know if you have any questions or need to see my code.

Comment: I am still having this issue. setting the MaxDepth = 0 makes nested menu moving impossible. any other solution found?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

figured it out. set maxDepth to 0 to try to get rid of the nesting capability (why use nestable without nesting? stupid i know). switching it to 1 solved the problem.

Comment: I face same issue in nestable. Can you please make your code here

Answer (score 0):

Edit nestable.js and add style min-height to:

```
if (!this.dragRootEl.find(opt.itemNodeName).length) {
  this.dragRootEl.append('<div class="' + opt.emptyClass + '" style="min-height:30px">');
}
```

Then you will drag to an empty list